# indexing frequently updated columns

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am in a confusion whether to index or not. I have a table that has 4 `boolean` columns. These columns are updated frequently by the employees. At the same time I have to perform select queries(with no complex joins) on these 4 columns a lot. Indexing these columns will affect the performance of updating or writing, on the other hand will improve the performance of select queries. Should I index them? I am using MariaDB and the table will have no more than 25-30 thousand rows in next 2 years. I will have to perform about 50-60 thousand(max) select queries on these 4 columns and 40-50 thousand(max) update queries during daytime.

Comment: MySQL may not have to rebuild the entire index with each update.  The answer really depends on how much you read vs. write, size of your tables, types of queries etc.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and some of the `UPDATEs` and `SELECTs`.  Otherwise, any answer here would be "hand waving" and may or may not really apply to _your_ situation.

Comment: And 30K rows is "small", so I expect we can 'make it work'.